# How does copyright on sources work

Tags: assets, legal

If I want to create a game in which I use sources from another game that has copyright is illegal. But what if I use screenshots from a 3D game to make another 2D game (something like a questionnaire)? Or what if I use the 3D models from the first game, render them with a program like cinema4D or blender in 2D and use them in the 2D game? And if it is illegal please explain me why and what laws of copyright would apply in that case.

I know that observing how a game works or any software for that matter and then reverse engineering it is legal so doing the same thing with resources from a game is legal. That's why I wanted to make clear my question is not related to reverse engineering.

Comment: You want us to list you the copyright laws that would apply in this situation?

Comment: not really only if it is illegal i want to know what laws make it illegal

Comment: This really belongs on [Law SE](http://law.stackexchange.com), but if you're using screenshots to provide a background for a 2D game, that to me falls under [Derivative Work](http://copyright.gov/circs/circ14.pdf)

Comment: Using in game A images/assets from game B, whether it is from the original assets or it is from a screenshot, is illegal (protected by copyright laws). If you make game A, copyright holders of game B could start legal actions against you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about interpreting copyright law in a broad variety of scenarios.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You use them in the procedure, to create your game. That's pretty much illegal. Just create models yourself, that's tbe easiest way to avoid license and copyright issues.

It's like uploading an image from a random person to your facebook page. The person isn't the picture, the person is only on the picture, but it is still illegal.

Comment: I'm not sure your comparison to the situation with facebook is applicable in this context.

Comment: It's just an example, to make it more visual.

Comment: Well I thought so. Anyway I asked this question because one of my friends suggested me a game (World of Tanks) that had all the resources I needed while I was working on creating my own resources. I was going to use my textures anyway because I made them with the game in mind and the models from WOT are way too high res for my game but I was curios to see if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, sadly. You might want to consult a real lawyer to determine exactly what should be done, however there is a great answer in general about [using one form of art](http://www.artbusiness.com/copyprobs.html) to make another at another website. Highlights:

- If you are using a large number of sources to get a feel, but putting together your own work, you are probably okay.
- If you are directly copying a work, you probably aren't okay.
- If it is your own interpretation of the artwork, you are probably fine. Using a 2D model to build a 3D model is probably okay, especially if you put your own edge to it.
- If in doubt, contact the artist.

So bottom line, don't directly copy anyone's work, but you can use other people's work to make your own if you are using it for inspiration.